# Use HEX color in bootstrap Class

Tags: bootstrap-4

Normally I use for the background color in bootstrap as

```
<div class="bg-danger">Color in div</div>
```

Here I want the background color in HEX #0277bd.
How can I use this HEX color code in the bootstrap without using the css.

Comment: the color that gets rendered/displayed on the screen is due to CSS, if you want to change color (using javascript or jQuery), you'd have to use CSS

Comment: is there any way to put the color as <div class="bg-#0277bd">Color in div</div>

Comment: you're better off using inline style for this... `<div style="background: #0277bd">`

Comment: @AkberIqbal, inline styles are to be avoided. A custom color class or class override in a stylesheet is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap doesn’t include color and background-color utilities for every color variable, but you can generate these yourself with the utility API and extended Sass maps added in v5.1.0.

There instructions on how to accomplish creating utility classes via the API are in [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/colors/#generating-utilities), but I imagine it would be much simpler to either add inline styles or simply modify the class in the external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution in a comment (`class="bg-#0277bd"`) has some problems. For one, you wouldn't use a hash symbol in a class name, per [HTML spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448981/1264804).

Then, you wouldn't name your class for a specific color. You'd name it semantically for its purpose or intent, [as Bootstrap does](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/colors/#background-color), like `bg-accent`.

However, the best solution is usually to [override Bootstrap's color scheme](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/theming/#color) with a custom stylesheet or a custom SASS configuration, assuming that the semantic name of one of the colors suits your purpose.